# Get a document from couchbase lite database swift

Tags: swift, couchbase-lite

I want to retrieve a document from database to update it, so I need the document ID, how to get this ID if I didn't create the document with a custom ID (I've used database.createDocument() instead of database.documentWithID("docId"))

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created the document with a custom Id then you can use
 some other uniquely identifying property (or properties) of the document to query for the specific document.
Instead of querying and iterating over entire list of documents to find the match, you can create a [view](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html) with the specified property/properties as index. You can then [query](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/query/query/index.html) for that view with startKey / endKey set to the desired property value. That will return the document of interest.

Alternatively,if it's an option, create the document with a custom ID.